# Efficiently Composing a Dialog using BlockUI and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a small wrapper for the fantastic [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin used in my application to easily create dialogs that meet my needs.

Sometimes I am a bit jQuery retarded and would like to know from any of the aficionados out there how they would do this particular task.

This function creates a header, middle and footer custom to my application. Uses some passed in options to fill out the HTML further. Composes the dialog and then inserts it into the [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin.

```
function blockApp(element, options){
    var header = jQuery('<div class="modal-header clearfix"><h2></h2><span><a href="#"></a></span></div>'),
        center = jQuery('<div class="modal-content"></div>'),
        footer = jQuery('<div class="modal-footer"></div>');

    //Compose dialog
    var opts = jQuery.extend({}, dialogDefaults, options);
    header.find('h2').html(opts.title);
    center.html(jQuery(element).html());

    var comp = jQuery('<div></div>').append(header).append(center).append(footer);

    jQuery('#notificationUI').block(jQuery.extend({}, standardBlock, {
        message: comp,
    }));
    jQuery('.blockOverlay').click(function(){
        jQuery('#notificationUI').unblock();
    });             
}
```

I tried using wrap() and wrapInner() at first with no success also.

My question is **How would John Resig do this**?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I've recently used BlockUI w/ another jQuery plug-in called jConfirm which you can download from [here](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/). With the jConfirm (or jAlert or jPrompt) you can fully customize your alert box via CSS. My scenario is probably way different than yours but in my app, user's can make changes to a document. If they choose to click my "cancel" button to erase all of their changes I have a jConfirm alert pop up while using BlockUI to dim out the interface from them. It looks pretty slick. Using jQuery I can catch the click event of my "cancel" button and do something like:

```
$('.cancel').click(function () {

                $.alerts.dialogClass = 'my_css';

                $.blockUI({ message: null });

                jConfirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?', 'Cancel Changes?',

                function (r) {
                    if (r.toString() == 'false') {
                        $.unblockUI();
                    } else {
                        //close window
                    }
                });

                return false;

            });
```

Hope this helps!